# Trying to find a string with RLIKE that contains [text]

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to find all strings in my database that have a format as folowed
sometext [sometext] sometext. I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT AlbumName
FROM album
WHERE AlbumName RLIKE '.*[.*].*';
```

The problem I think I have that  `RLIKE` takes `[.*] as [a-z]` and I get back everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`escape`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) the character `[` and `]`

```
SELECT AlbumName
FROM album
WHERE AlbumName RLIKE '.*\\[.*\\].*';
```

Comment: @Tenebris np, nice day to you.